# Passing parameter from php to batch file and vise versa

Tags: php, batch-file

I am trying to pass variables from a php file to batch file and again want to get the output from batch file php file.

I think I cant use exec() or passthru() as there is no passing parameter option. Is there any other wayout.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to execute something from php I use the backticks.

```
$output = `my_script var1`;
```

Note that those are not single quotes but the backtick character (to the left of the "1" key on my keyboard).

More information can be found in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php